# install a library if necessary

Tags: python, pip, python-import

i wanted to send a short code i was proud of to a fellow student and realized he won't be able to run it since there is no reason for him to have installed the library.
installing is of course super easy - but i realized this could happen often, mainly with beginners - wanted to build a simple function for it:

```
def smart_import(package_name):
    try:
        import package_name
    except ImportError:
        import pip
        pip.main(['install', package_name])
```

problem is that i dont really know how to pass in the name of the package as a value that could be called by import
thought of converting a string back but that seems more complicated then i thought

Comment: how do you call this function?

Comment: Eh.... [wheels](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#wheels) are a much better way to solve this problem

Comment: Beginners should get used to the idea of installing packages. Depending on the system configuration, mainly permission settings, your script may not be capable of installing packages itself, and that's sane.

Comment: It is extremely common to have to install libraries to execute or compile code in all languages. It really shouldn't be considered an issue for them to have to install it. The only exception would be end users. But, for reference, you would probably want to use importlib.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bad idea for many reasons, the main one being that people generally don't expect a Python function call to automatically attempt to install software on their machine.

**Here are some other problems this approach has**:

- The import name is not always corresponding to the distribution name.  For example `dateutil` module is provided by `python-dateutil` distribution.
- If you try to use `smart_import` from another module, it will leave the name imported into the wrong namespace.
- Some distributions export multiple top-level imports, e.g. `setuptools` provides `setuptools`, `easy_install`, and `pkg_resources`.
- In some cases, `pip` itself may not be installed.
- The script might not have permission to install packages.
- The user might want to install distributions into their homedir explicitly with `--user`, and your script itself can't know that.
- The invocation of `pip` might need to change depending on whether or not you are within a virtualenv.
- The installation might attempt to pull in dependencies which cause conflicts with other distributions a user has installed.
- IDEs likely won't see that a module dynamically imported is there, and may squiggly underline their subsequent use as a name which can not be resolved.

**What to do instead:**

Package your code up into its own distribution.  Write a `setup.py` which mentions the dependencies using the `install_requires` argument to in the `setup` call.  Ask your fellow student to `pip install mypackage`, and the dependencies will be collected at install time rather than at runtime.  You can send your distribution directly to them (as a `mypackage-0.1.tar.gz` file or as a [wheel](https://pythonwheels.com/)).  Or you can upload it to an index such as the [test pypi](https://testpypi.python.org/PyPI).

The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) is a beginner-friendly resource describing how to create and upload your own distribution.